# Finding repeating patterns in data. E.g. Which is the most popular selection of subjects chosen by students?

Tags: excel, design-patterns, excel-formula

Let's say I have 4 students, and each has to choose 3 subjects from a selection of 6.

Now I have the results, I want to find a pattern which shows me the most popular selection of results.

John: Science, Maths, English
Bill: Science, Maths, French
Dave: Science, English, French
Simon: Science, Maths, English

As the above example is so small, it is easy to see that the most popular choice is Science, Maths, English.

But is there a way to query a spreadsheet with a bigger selection of data?

Comment: How do you want to query the spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi Chris, could you explain the format that the data is kept in? This will affect the way the question is answered

Answer (score 0):

There two scenarios: -

The data is in 2 columns the first containing the names and the second containing the options as text fields, as below:

```
    A       B
1   John    Science, Maths, English
2   Bill    Science, Maths, French
3   Dave    Science, English, French
4   Simon   Science, English, Maths
```

To query these fields, you would need to use a formula like:

```
={SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("English",B1:B4,1)),1,0)}
```

The result of this is 3 (press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to add the curly brackets, which indicate an array formula). You could put this in a table like so:

```
Science 4
English 3
Maths   3
French  2
```

If your subjects are in separate columns, simply use a COUNTIF on the entire data range:

```
    A       B          C        D
1   John    Science    Maths    English
2   Bill    Science    Maths    French
3   Dave    Science    English  French
4   Simon   Science    English  Maths
```

Your formula would be:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$D$4,"English")
```

Which would also work! Hope that helps, Mike